# Why is stringified JSON a valid string?

Tags: javascript, json

We're already aware that we cannot add double quotes inside the double quotes:

`var str = ""hello"";` //this will be invalid string

but when I stringify an object like this

```
var obj = {"name":"abc"}
var str = JSON.stringify(obj).
str // returns "{"name":"abc"}"
```

which is valid but shouldn't be. I'm confused as in do JavaScript have some special cases when we stringify a JSON object and omit the string validations on it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just how your console represents the string for display. A more valid example would be `'{"name":"abc"}'`

Comment: The developers of your Javascript console have merely chosen a confusing way to display strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many double quotes inside a string literal as you want. You just need to scape them using a backslash prefix (\" instead of ").
Try this example in your browser console:

```
var myStr = "\"Hello\"";
myStr
```

You should see `""Hello""` in your console. That would be how the stringify creates a string with double quotes in it.